# Convergence in probability of product of sample means

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Let $\bar{X_n}$ and $\bar{Y_n}$ be the sample means of random samples from two different distributions with finite means and variances. I'm confused about the following result.

Consider

$\bar{X_n}\bar{Y_n} = (\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i)(\frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} Y_j)$
$=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n} X_iY_j$

$\mathbb{E}[\bar{X_n}\bar{Y_n}]=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_iY_j]$
$=\frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{E}[X_1Y_1]$
$=\frac{n^2}{n^2} \mathbb{E}[X_1Y_1]$
$=\mathbb{E}[X_1Y_1]$

$\mathbb{Var}[\bar{X_n}\bar{Y_n}]=1/n^4 \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{Var}[X_iY_j]$
$=\frac{1}{n^4} \sum_{i=1}^{n} \sum_{j=1}^{n}\mathbb{Var}[X_1Y_1]$
$=\frac{n^2}{n^4} \mathbb{Var}[X_1Y_1]$
$=\frac{1}{n^2} \mathbb{Var}[X_1Y_1]$

I'm not sure if this is correct, but if it is then using Chebyshev's inequality

$\bar{X_n}\bar{Y_n} \xrightarrow{\text{p}} \mathbb{E}[X_1Y_1]$

Since,

$\frac{1}{n^2\epsilon^2} \mathbb{Var}[X_1Y_1] \rightarrow 0 \text{ as } n \rightarrow \infty$

However, from Theorem 5.1.5. Hogg, Craig

If $X_n \xrightarrow{p} X$ and $Y_n \xrightarrow{p} Y$. Then $X_nY_n \xrightarrow{p} XY$

If I replace $X_n$ and $Y_n$ with $\bar{X_n}$ and $\bar{Y_n}$ respectively then,

$X_nY_n \xrightarrow{p} \mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong but I don't know what.

Comment: In your second line how did you get $EX_iY_j=EX_1Y_1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are also assuming that $(X_i)$ is independent of $(Y_i)$. Without this you cannot say that $EX_iY_j=EX_1Y_1$. Since $X_1$ and $Y_1$ are independent, the limits you have obtanined are one and the same.

Here is a counter-example to $EX_iY_j=EX_1Y_1$: Let $(X_i)$ be i.i.d. $N(0,1), Y_i=X_i$ for $i>1$ and $Y_1=-X_1$. Then $(Y_i)$ is also i.i.d. $N(0,1)$ but $EX_2Y_2=1,EX_1Y_1=-1$.

Comment: Why is there  a downvote? Could someone kindly  explain?

Comment: It's not me. But if $X_i$'s are independent and $Y_i$'s are independent, doesn't this mean that $X_i Y_i$ and $X_j Y_j$ are independent?

Comment: No, that is not true and  I have added counter-example to that claim. @Valeron

Comment: Makes sense. Let me rethink.